# How to midify MSE loss function for training an autoencoder?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, autoencoder

I am training an autoencoder with Dense layers. Its input is a vector containing the positions of several
objects in 3D space. each of the objects corresponds to a set of 5 points,
defining its position, each point is defined by 3 coordinates in 3D.
That. the input vector of the neural network looks like this: x11, y11, z11, x12, y12, z12 ... x21, y21,
z21, ... xnm, ynm, znm. After training, during validation
it was found that the last objects in the row turn out to be displaced relative to the desired position
too much.

Preparing input data to extract the most relevant label data
difficult, because the dataset is too large, and problematic objects end up in different places in the vector,
because the number of objects itself varies from case to case. How can I modify the loss function
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss() to achieve the desired result in the learning process?